# How to return json data from spring controller in apache sling and neba environment

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, sling, jackson-databind

I am using [Neba library](http://localhost:8080/bin/mvc.do/category/list) along with [Apache sling](http://sling.apache.org/).

Now my spring controller working fine with this code.

```
@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/category/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

after hitting url http://localhost:8080/bin/mvc.do/category/list

I am getting response "**Hello World!**"

But when I am trying to return List String like this -

```
@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/category/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> sayHello() {
        return new Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","B","C"});
    }
}
```

I am getting following exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

I do have jackson databind in my library

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also checked bundle jar it has these library in lib. Still not sure why it doesn't work. Any help is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Spring's support for JSON conversion from Controller responses, deploy the jackson-databind, jackson-core, jackson-annotations bundles. Spring then picks up the these bundles (this may require a refresh/restart of Sling) and automatically adds new message converters which use jackson to convert the Objects returned by a @Controller's method to JSON, for example:

```
@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/category/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<String> sayHello() {
        return Arrays.asList("A","B","C");
    }
}
```

Note: It is really these jackson bundles that must be deployed. The availability of the jackson packages alone would not be enough, as the Spring bundles shipped with NEBA have optional require-bundle (not import-package) dependencies to jackson (see [neba-155](https://github.com/unic/neba/issues/155) for why that is).

The [NEBA sample project](https://github.com/unic/neba-sample-project) now includes the jackson bundles, so you can use it as a starting point to try automatic JSON conversion from controller responses.

Regarding Tim's comment above, one does *not* have to convert manually.  Spring MVC can do so automatically based on content-negotiation via the request's "Accept" header and the available Spring Message Converters, see *$ 28.10.2 HTTP Message Conversion* in the Spring Docs.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return JSON with RestController and Jackson, you have to use an **ObjectMapper** like this :

```
@RestController
public class CategoryController {
    //Add produces application/json
    @RequestMapping(value = "/category/list", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public List<String> sayHello() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Object to JSON in String
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A","B","C"}));
        return jsonInString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Spring MVC does it by itself if jackson-databind jar is in classpath?

Comment: No, adding jackson-databind in classpath just allow you to use ObjectMapper for parse from/to Json Object

Comment: I disagree with you. I have worked on many of the spring project and just returning object is more than enough as long as i have jackson-databind in my classpath. I have never serialized in json manually.

Comment: I always parse manually but you can do it easily by just adding produces = "application/json" in your RequestMapping